# NSDateformatter: How to decide date formatter string

Tags: date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

Is there any rule to define date formatter?
I have date string as given below
**Mon Feb 10 09:05:13 PST 2014**
How to do i write appropriate date format for this date string to convert date?

```
 NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE-MMM-DD-hh:mm:ss-Z-YYYY"];
 NSDate * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

Above formatter doesn't work and returns nil. Tried few other options as well.

What should be the delimiters in format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE-MMM-dd-hh:mm:ss-z-yyyy"];
```

The pattern is case sensitive. For more information see [here](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: The document you provide helped. Thanks